# How to refactor code in order to avoid label in a Java loop?

Tags: java, loops, refactoring, label

How can I refactor my code to remove the label and the need for it ?
I am aware that a loop with label is "forbidden". But I can not find a way to rewrite this without the label.

Any ideas ? Thanks

```
private List<myList> sortLinks(SegmentType s, Set<myList> LinkSet) {
        List<myList> LinkList = new LinkedList<myList>();

        String dep = s.getDep().toString();
        mainLoop: for (int index = 0; !LinkSet.isEmpty(); index++) {

            for (Iterator<myList> iterator = LinkSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                myList link = iterator.next();
                if (link.getLegDep().toString().equals(dep)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    link.setLine(s.getLineCode());
                    link.setNb(s.getNb());
                    link.setSuff(s.getSuff());
                    link.setIndex(index);
                    linkList.add(link);

                    dep = link.getDest().toString();
                    continue mainLoop;
                }
            }

            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return linkList;
    }
```

Comment: try [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - They might be in better position of advising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need a `boolean`.  I don't completely understand what your code is trying to accomplish, but it looks like the inner loop is trying to find a "dependency" of some kind?  If that's the case, I'd name the `boolean` `depedencyFound`; if I've really guessed wrong, you can call it something else.  Anyway, something like this:

```
private List<myList> sortLinks(SegmentType s, Set<myList> LinkSet) {
    List<myList> LinkList = new LinkedList<myList>();

    String dep = s.getDep().toString();
    for (int index = 0; !LinkSet.isEmpty(); index++) {

        boolean dependencyFound = false;
        for (Iterator<myList> iterator = LinkSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            myList link = iterator.next();
            if (link.getLegDep().toString().equals(dep)) {
                iterator.remove();
                link.setLine(s.getLineCode());
                link.setNb(s.getNb());
                link.setSuff(s.getSuff());
                link.setIndex(index);
                linkList.add(link);

                dep = link.getDest().toString();
                dependencyFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!dependencyFound) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

If you name the variable right, it will make it pretty clear what's going on.  Here, you look for a dependency; if you don't find one, you return an empty list; if you do, then you iterate again through the main loop.

P.S. Once you've done that, then it may be fairly easy to take the whole inner loop and move it to a method that returns a `boolean`, although it looks like it will also need to return a `String` with the new value of `dep`.  But if you find a way to do this, it will clean up your code even more.

Comment: Hi ajb, thanks for your answer. I don't think I am able to make the method returning a boolean for the inner loop, especially since you are talking about returning a String. Any suggestions to clear my mind ?

Comment: One possibility: extract the inner loop into a method that returns `myList`.  If one is found, it returns the `myList` that you find (`link`).  If it isn't found, it returns `null`.  Then instead of using a `boolean` the outer loop would say `if (foundLink==null) return Collections.emptyList();`, and if it isn't `null` then the outer loop would set `dep` based on the `foundLink`.  Just some possible ideas.  Shorter methods tend to improve readability, but there's a point of diminishing returns if you have to complicate things too much.  It's a judgment call.

Comment: regarding the boolean, I was wondering if I need to set it reight after my `String dep = s.getDep().toString();` line, or inside the `for` loop like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Actually eurythmia answer is kind of correct.
You can use boolean value to continue like this:

```
private List<myList> sortLinks(SegmentType s, Set<myList> LinkSet) {
    List<myList> LinkList = new LinkedList<myList>();

    String dep = s.getDep().toString();
    for (int index = 0; !LinkSet.isEmpty(); index++) {

        for (Iterator<myList> iterator = LinkSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            myList link = iterator.next();
            boolean toContinue = false;
            if (link.getLegDep().toString().equals(dep)) {
                iterator.remove();
                link.setLine(s.getLineCode());
                link.setNb(s.getNb());
                link.setSuff(s.getSuff());
                link.setIndex(index);
                linkList.add(link);

                dep = link.getDest().toString();
                toContinue = true;
                break; // this breaks inner loop
            }
        }
        if(toContinue) {
            continue; // this continues main loop without executing the 'return'
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

since the `continue` is at the end of the inner loop, simply using `break` should start the next iteration of the main loop.

Comment: How can I avoid using the label then ?

Comment: You don't need the label when using the break keyword. It will break out of the inner loop, returning control to the outer loop (which, since it is at the end of an iteration will continue on to the next iteration of the outer loop with no further instruction).

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Using `break` will exit the inner loop and jump to the statement after the inner loop, which is `return Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your exponation eurythmia.

Comment: @ajb you are correct ... I missed that in my read over of the problem. Your answer takes this into account, and I have upvoted accordingly.